# How to order Grid having selected rows always as first / top rows of Grid?

Tags: java, sorting, grid, vaadin, comparator

I'd like to set on a Vaadin Grid component the selected rows (on a Multiselect mode) as the first shown, i.e., order by selected rows.

Does anybody know if that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I present here one solution that has four points which need attention. There might be more elegant solution though.

1. There is a  need for a comparator that can check the selection status of item
2. Comparator needs to take account sorting order
3. Sorting is column based
4. Unselected rows need to be sorted anyway with the default sort method / comparator and perhaps also selected rows amongst other selected.

**Points 1 & 2** are satisfied by creating `Comparator` that implements also `SortEvent.SortListener`

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
// above is a lombok annotation to generate constructor
// SelectedFirstComparator(grid, defaultComparator);
public class SelectedFirstComparator<T>
        implements SerializableComparator<T>, SortListener<GridSortOrder<T>> {
    private final Grid<T> grid; // used to dig selected rows
    // defaultComparator is used when selection status is not taken 
    // account to handle rest of sorting, related to point 4   
    private final SerializableComparator<T> defaultComparator; 
    // sortOrder is used to inverse the sorting order between
    // selected & not selected items
    // if not used selected items will change between first & last rows 
    // and we need them always first 
    private int sortOrder = 1; 
    @Override
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        boolean o1Selected = grid.getSelectedItems().contains(o1);
        boolean o2Selected = grid.getSelectedItems().contains(o2);
        // if one is selected and one is not the selected one "wins"
        if(o1Selected && !o2Selected) return 1 * sortOrder;
        if(!o1Selected && o2Selected) return -1 * sortOrder;
        // if both are selected arrange amongst first rows
        // with default comparator
        // if both are not-selected arrange them to natural order
        // with default comparator
        return defaultComparator.compare(o1, o2);
    }

    // This method is listening the sort order change
    // and updating the sortOrder to keep selected rows as firts 
    @Override
    public void sort(SortEvent<GridSortOrder<T>> event) {
        switch(event.getSortOrder().get(0).getDirection()) {
        case ASCENDING:
            sortOrder = -1;
            break;
        case DESCENDING:
            sortOrder = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Point 3**

You need to add instance of `SelectedFirstComparator` as comparator for every sortable column, like

```
col1.setComparator(col1Comparator);
col2.setComparator(col2Comparator);
...
```

For each colXcomparator you need to provide the corresponding default comparator handling that column default ordering when constructing. If col1 is of type `String` it will be something like

```
SelectedFirstComparator<GridEntity> col1Comparator = 
    new SelectedFirstComparator<GridEntity>( grid, (e11, e12) -> {
        return e11.getName().compareTo(e12.getName());
    }
);
```

**Point 4**

To have comparators ot monitor sort order and `sort()` method update sortOrder you need to register all comparators to grid as `SortListener`

```
grid.addSortListener(col1Comparator);
grid.addSortListener(col2Comparator);
...
```